# Ffmpeg converting to mp4 from mkv[mpeg@ 0x7f9c19800000] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I recently converted a number of anime episodes from MKV to MP4 to burn and watch on my SamsungBRPlayer, however during the process I wasn't able to convert the subtitle stream #0:2 through ffmpeg from .ssa to .srt thru their respective codecs (SSA to MOV_TEXT, can also be SUBRIP). I eventually decided to extract the SSA files and encode them as .srt... one for each episode. I converted these to .srt and plugged them back into the 8 episodes.

`for i in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$i" -i *.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -c:v h264_videotoolbox -c:a aac -b:a 128k -target ntsc-dvd -y "yfolder/${i%.mkv*}.mp4"; done`

After testing the compatibility of these files I know that this video codec will work, and the BluRay player I use also recognizes the subtitle files; However , when looking back at the streams #0:0 which is where the subtitles are stored gives me "[mpeg @ 0x7f8621000000] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts." This stream #0:O is now a data stream...0:1 video 0:2 being audio ... 
One of the reasons I thought that I could have received this message is from an Attachment from the original MKV files in the #0:3 stream, which because it wasn't anything more than metadata I ignored. 
Another would probably be from the code mentioned above importing multiple .srt files into each of the new .mp4 files. I did find a solution however I'm not able to utilize the coding.

```
$ for video in *.mkv 
do 
base=${video%.mkv} ffmpeg -i $base.mkv -vf subtitles=$base.srt  
$base-out.mkv ; done
```

I couldn't seem to get it to work. My files were as follows:

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 001 [720p] [suitup].mp4

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 002 [720p] [suitup].mp4

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 003 [720p] [suitup].mp4

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 004 [720p] [suitup].mp4

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 005 [720p] [suitup].mp4

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 006 [720p] [suitup].mp4

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 007 [720p] [suitup].mp4

[AnimeGT] Hansom Gold - 008 [720p] [suitup].mp4

So the titles are obviously fake but whatever. What I need to know is how to use the `${I%.*}.mp4` and `${h%.*}.srt` to represent both the base and the video variables in the coding I failed at above. 
While keeping the data stream from each file. 
if that's the problem. Some help would be nice.

`[mpeg @ 0x7f9c19800000] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts`

I need to know how to deal with this.

Comment: By adding `-target ntsc-dvd`, you're now using mpeg2video encoder which is producing that message. Remove it.